# Android Emitter.Listener not working

Tags: android, socket.io

I'm making an app with socket IO, it connects correctly to the server, but it doesn't listen to events.

Here's part of my code:

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(ip+":8000");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ads);

    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
    mSocket.connect();
    mSocket.on("send file", onSendFile);
}

private Emitter.Listener onSendFile = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        String data = (String) args[0];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mSocket.emit("fileok", "OKIDOKI");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to show toast on UI thread instead of different thread using `getActivity().runOnUiThread`

```
private Emitter.Listener onSendFile = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        String data = (String) args[0];

        mSocket.emit("fileok", "OKIDOKI");

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    }
};
```