# Socket Cluster. Emitter.Listener not working

Tags: java, android, socketcluster

First of all this question has no duplicate, because in this question there's only toast problem [[Android Emitter.Listener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001902/android-emitter-listener-not-working][1]). I have no problem with toast. I'm using `SocketCluster` https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-java, not `Sokcet.IO` .  So my problem is, that `Emitter.Listener` not works. I'm connecting successfully, but in that listener i need to give my tokens, else in server there will be some exceptions. *Server says that it not gets PONG from client.*

Now I'll add link and there are pictures. There I'm explaining my problem very well, so you can understand easier.

Here's the code too.

```
  public void socketCall(final JSONObject jsonObject) {

  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          Emitter.Listener listener = new Emitter.Listener() {
              @Override
              public void call(String name, Object data) {
                  Log.d("4564323", "AAA");
                  data = jsonObject;
                  sc.emit("auth", data);
              }
          };



sc.on("connect" , listener);

 sc.createChannel(
 SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUsername());

  sc.connect();



if(!sc.isconnected()) {
              sc.setReconnection(new 
              ReconnectStrategy().setDelay(2000).setMaxAttempts(10));
          }
          Log.d("4564323", socket.getCurrentState().toString());

      }
  });

thread.start();

}
```